# Using statprof to profile a Django view - can not use signals in thread

Tags: python, django, profiling

[statprof](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/statprof/) is a statistical profiling tool for Python. The docs say that it can only be used to profile the main thread. So if you use it to profile some function that is called during processing request when using `./manage.py runserver`, it raises ValueError: signal only works in main thread.

I see two possible ways to solve this problem (apart from calling function from the console, which is possible, but not as convenient):

1) Hacking statprof, so that it does not use signals - but it is not obvious how to do it, or if it is possible at all.

2) Making runserver command run everything in the main thread.

Maybe there are other solutions? Has anyone used statprof in django views?

Answer (score 0):

If you do `./manage.py runserver --noreload` when using statprof, it will run the development server in a single thread and work around this issue.

Comment: does not work for me. However, `./manage.py --noreload --nothreading` does.